# DBIx and inheritance in Perl

Tags: perl, inheritance, dbix-class

I'm currently trying to implement the following scenario with DBIx:

The table **products** contains "general products" and "bundle products" (bundle products are collections of general products):

```
package Product;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("products");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "productId",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 10},
  "name",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 1, size => 150},
  "type",
  {
     data_type => "enum",
     default_value => "general",
     extra => {
       list => ["general", "bundle"],
     },
     is_nullable => 0,
  });
```

As you can see, wether the product is a **general** product or a **bundle** product is saved in the column **type**.

Now I would like to encapsulate this information in the class identity: I would like to have following classes:

- Product (`type` does not matter)
- BundleProduct (`type` = 'bundle')
- GeneralProduct (`type` = 'general')

I wrote:

```
package BundleProduct;
use base 'Product';

__PACKAGE__->resultset_attributes({ where => { 'type' => 'bundle' } });
1;
```

and

```
package GeneralProduct;
use base 'Product';

__PACKAGE__->resultset_attributes({ where => { 'type' => 'general' } });
1;
```

But when executing

```
my @allProducts = $schema->resultset('BundleProduct')->all;
```

all **general** products are fetched. Although the resulting objects are of instance `BundleProduct`, the generated SQL contains the WHERE-condition of the class `GeneralProduct` (`type` = 'general'). Even worse: If I try to fetch a `Product` (base class of `BundleProduct` and `GeneralProduct`) the condition `type` = 'general' is applied, too! It seems that the definition within `GeneralProduct` overwrites all other definitions.

What is wrong with my design?

Answer (score 4):

The usage of `resultset_attributes` is not recommended. You should implement a result set class for `Product` with methods `bundle_products` and `general_products`:

```
package My::Schema::ResultSet::Product;
use base 'DBIx::Class::ResultSet';

sub bundle_products  { shift->search({ type => 'bundle' }); }
sub general_products { shift->search({ type => 'general' }); }
```

Then you can search specific products like this:

```
$schema->resultset('Product')->bundle_products->all;
$schema->resultset('Product')->general_products->all;
```

See the [documentation of resultset_attributes](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSource#resultset_attributes).

Also have a look at [DBIx::Class::DynamicSubclass](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aDynamicSubclass). It adds some useful features when subclassing results.

Comment: ++ for DBIx::Class::DynamicSubclass in this scenario

Comment: ... or do it "by hand" as described in the cookbook: http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08250/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Dynamic_Sub-classing_DBIx::Class_proxy_classes_%28AKA_multi-class_object_inflation_from_one_table%29

Answer (score 0):

It may always be defaulting to *general* because the data is not being inflated to an Enum object?

Surprised that it doesn't give a clear error but perhaps adding below (to `Product` package) will fix your problem:

```
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw/InflateColumn::Object::Enum/);
```

Additional to above also try adding `is_enum => 1` to your *type* column definition:

```
type => {
  data_type     => "enum",
  is_enum       => 1,  
  default_value => "general",
  is_nullable   => 0,
  extra => {
    list => ["general", "bundle"],
  },
},
```

NB. This should enforce the use of the inflation object (`Object::Enum`) whereas without it I believe it tries to use the *enum* native to the RDBMS you're using (if its present).

Fingers crossed this works.  If not try removing the `default_value` to see how this affects things.

Comment: @dreagtun Thank you, but I think that InflateColumn::Object::Enum is only designated for converting `varchar` fields into `enum` fields within the application.
[link](http://search.cpan.org/~jmmills/DBIx-Class-InflateColumn-Object-Enum-0.04/lib/DBIx/Class/InflateColumn/Object/Enum.pm)

Comment: Looking at the tests provided by `DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::Object::Enum` module the author always loads the component and also sets `is_enum => 1`.  Here's the test that matches what you're trying todo in your example: https://metacpan.org/source/JMMILLS/DBIx-Class-InflateColumn-Object-Enum-0.04/t/lib/TestDB/NativeEnumNoneNullable.pm   The author maybe being over zealous but it maybe worth a try.   Also author provides no `default_value` tests so there could be an issue there?  Anyway I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly OT, but I seem to always run into some insidious application implementation problem when dealing with enum data types in my schemas.

So I don't use them any more. I use foreign key relationships and either individual tables or a combined table holding all codes:

```
<id, code_type, code_name> 
< 1, 'product_type', 'bundle'>
< 2, 'product_type', 'general'>
```

and then I join from product to product_type on product.product_type_id = code_table.id

This technique has made application implementation much, much easier at the cost of some additional database management in the beginning of the project.

Comment: You can avoid the join by making a `product_types` table with a single field, the type name, which has a unique constraint and is a foreign key into the `products` table. The foreign key will enforce the limited set of values for the field, and since the key is the name rather than a number, there's no need to do extra joins.

Comment: True. but I no longer use data for keys.  No matter how hard I try, somebody eventually wants to change the key data and then you have all the extra work getting those updates done.  If the code is used often, it will be in memory so the join won't take much time.  Why on earth is everybody afraid of joins?